# How does the Simple Deform modifier work under the hood in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to make sense of how Simple Deform works. Right now it makes no sense to me.

First, if I make a cube, scale it down and subdivide it, then use the Simple Deform (SD from now on), I get the results I expect. Then if I create an empty and assign it to SD's Axis,Origin, I still get the results I expect (that is, I can tell beforehand how & why the mesh will deform).

Then if I make a plane, scale it twice along the X axis, apply scale, subdivide it and then use SD, weird things happen. First off, the plane remains unchanged with the Axis being X/Y (no Empty chosen yet). The same result happens when I assign an empty with no rotation.

Then if I rotate the empty 90 degree along the X axis, choose Axis as X, the plane now bend along the X axis, like this:

[image]

This makes no sense, becasue the empty's X remain unchanged because I rotate it along the X axis. The only thing changed is its Z aligns with the Global Y and its Y aligns with the Global Z. If the empty's X being unchanged, then why I coudn't achieve this result choosing the X as Axis with the empty before rotation?

Also, when I rotate the empty 90 degree only along the Y axis, choose Z as Axis, then it... twists instead of bending, like this:

[image]

In the SD tutorials, the speakers always rotate the empty 90 degree along X/Y axis and then use Simple Deform without explaining why they have to rotate the empty. For example: [Simple Deform Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr49AyeM8p4&t=)

Comment: In case you think this question is so basic, I would like to post here a link in which developers discuss the same thing: https://developer.blender.org/T62080. It seems the Bending mode of Simple Deform modifier doesn't work properly. It's very unintuitive.

Comment: Agreed. I have gone backwards and forwards trying to reverse-engineer the logic of the Bend modifier, and I'm stumped. I wind up with a few set empty-based configurations I know to work, and fall back on them.

Comment: Have tried to find some explanation. Don't know what is your opinion about it? (@RobinBetts) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135973/rotating-an-empty-different-results/149642#149642

Comment: @lemon He he! .. I already UV'd that one, for effort! It kind of works for me..  I'll give my attempt an outing here, when I can.. there's just one function/mapping  I can't really work out.. would you know where to look in the source code?

Comment: @RobinBetts, that's here https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/master/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_simpledeform.c Did not dig in it, but at first quick read this does not seem to be totally symmetrical. To be deepen...

Comment: @RobinBetts, now in order to use this mode, I assign an Empty to it, then choose the axis I want to bend around and tweak the Empty's rotation (X-->Y-->Z) until I achieve the desired result. I feel shameful doing this, but I can't understand this mode conceptually. Once I know some code I'll revisit it by analyzing the codes.